# default_factory not being called on dataclasses' fields

Tags: python-3.x, python-dataclasses

Here is an example of what happens:

```
 @dataclass 
 class D: 
     prop1: str 
     prop2: dict = field(default_factory=lambda: defaultdict(set)) 

 d = D("spam")
 print(d)
 # D(prop1='spam', prop2=Field(name=None,type=None,default=<dataclasses._MISSING_TYPE object at 0x10274c650>,default_factory=<function D.<lambda> at 0x103ad3a70>,init=True,repr=True,hash=None,compare=True,metadata=mappingproxy({}),_field_type=None))
```

As you can see, the `prop2` was not initialized using a default value from the `default_factory`, it is still a field. And if I try to do `d.prop2["some key"]` I get `TypeError: 'Field' object is not subscriptable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have imported the `dataclass` decorator from the wrong module. It may happen if you use automatic imports in your IDE.

The behaviour described happens when you import `dataclass` from `attr` (`from attr import dataclass`). 
If you do `from dataclasses import dataclass` everything will work as expected (the `default_factory` will be called to generate the value of the field).